# Detect android TV with cordova / ionic

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-tv, ionic-native

I have a Ionic 3 project properly working on Android TV and on Android smartphone.

I would like to be specific actions when the user is using the TV app. I tried to use this :

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
...
if(this.platform.is('android') && !this.platform.is('mobile')) {
  this.isAndroidTV = true;
}
```

But it is detecting mobile to true on Android TV.
I suppose it is possible to detect TVs using the cordova "Device" plugin but I have not found how.

Hardware use for test : Xiaomi Mi Box with Android TV 6.0

Have a good day ! =D

Comment: Try debugging (printing on screen) all contents from the `device` array on all devices, then compare them to see if you find something useful. Certainly it will be hard to detect the TV if Cordova does not provide means to do that, so good luck!